# Python re.sub replace match with it's md5sum

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to parse such a string:

`<@Something> there is some regular text <@something_else> and even more <@foo> <@bar> text`

And replace all `<@tokens>` with theirs md5 sums.

Is it possible with python re.sub? How can I pass `@token` to a function and the function's output to `re.sub`?

So far I've tried the simplest approach with:

```
import re

def fun(str):
    return str.replace('@', '!')

pattern = r'(<@\w+>)'
string = '<@AAAA> some text and more text <@BBBBB>'

print fun('<@AAAA>')
print string
print re.sub(pattern, fun(r'\1'), string)
```

Without success. The fun function works as expected outside re.sub(), but not within it.

Comment: What happens if you use `re.sub(pattern, fun, str)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `hashlib` library:

```
import hashlib, re

s = '<@Something> there is some regular text <@something_else> and even more <@foo> <@bar> text'
result = re.sub(r'<@[^>]+>', lambda m: hashlib.md5(m.group().encode()).hexdigest(), s)

print(result)
```

The output:

```
eb6eae14fb79abc1339b7096ae00a5e9 there is some regular text 16960eadb21d27a1b52e5c71a5ae7357 and even more 281dc7c0420f8e6ef66e58ecb979d087 31c0c5b91906d520a4dec601241833a6 text
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) shows, the "replacement" parameter to `re.sub()` can be a function which takes a match object and returns the replacement.